# clustering based on thresholds

Tags: python, tree, hierarchy

EDIT (Simplified)

I am pretty sure, i am missing the right terms to "google" this question, please do point me to it if it has been asked before:
I have a tree structure, lets say as below

```
(0)->(0,0:7)
     (0,1:9)
(1)->(1,0:6)
     (1,1:2)
     (1,2:1)
```

For simplicity lets convert this into a flat structure

```
l1, l2, v1
0, 0, 7
0, 1, 9
1, 0, 6
1, 1, 2
1, 2, 1
```

Now lets put a threshold of `3` on this tree. Meaning we want to keep nodes that are above the threshold and merge all nodes in a branch which are below the threshold.

So what we end up with, is that the last two rows (as they are below the threshold) ending up with a note being 'yielded' as an aggregate of two:

```
l1, l2, v1
0, 0, 7
0, 1, 9
1, 0, 6
1, (1,2),  3
```

Ideally a solution in python would be appreciated. Obviously there would be edge conditions that I am happy to handle. Please note that in reality I can end up with tree which is 6 deep.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the help documentation for postings, especially http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  We are not a coding service.

Comment: That said, perhaps what you need is the "groupby" feature in some packages.  Also, we need more detail to guide you properly.  Are the first two columns required to match to support a clustering?  If not, what do we do with those?  For instance, if we have thresholds at 5 and 8.5, do we combine the two middle lines?  If so, how?

Comment: appreciate the  guide.. and i agree that SO aint a coding service :P. i was thinking more in terms of a derivation on the scipy hierarchical clustering. So to answer your question, 1) yes we need some level to match, 2) if the threshold was higher lets say 7 then we will merge the entire (1,0,:) branch so make it 1, 0, (0,1,2) as 9.

Comment: i have a soloution in my head which involved a depth first traversal with a stack on the side on , you start from the leaf, if the leaf is above the threshold, you move on to its sibling, if the sibling is below a threshold you push that particular node into a stack, once all children are traversed in a branch, i.e., you reach a root node (in my example l1)  or the threshold is met you empty the stack and move to the next branch. Feels like an overkill, but if this is what it is, this s what it is

Comment: I can't tell whether it's overkill -- yet.  I'll wait for the full question to appear.  Thanks.

Comment: updated the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally I did it in the cumbersome way I had hinted to earlier. 
I started with adding a few flags (`dodelete=False` and `visited=False`) to my node definition.

And updated the `add_node` method to

```
def add_child(self, node):
    node.parent = self
    node.level = self.level + 1
    self.children.append(node)
    return node
```

where `self.children` is a list of nodes

Then two methods

```
def collapse_nodes(tree, thresh=3):
    for n in tree:
        if n.dodelete:
            continue
        sub_tree = tree.get_by_path (n.id)
        sub_tree_stack = []
        for child in sub_tree.children:
           if child.val is not None and thresh > child.val:
               sub_tree_stack.append(child)
               tree.get_by_path(child.id).dodelete = True
           if sub_tree_stack:
              sub_tree.add_child(Node(",".join([subnode.name for subnode in sub_tree_stack]), 
                                 val = sum([subnode.val for subnode in sub_tree_stack]), 
                                 id= sorted([subnode.id for subnode in sub_tree_stack])[0]))
    return tree
```

and

```
def roll_up(tree, thresh = 2, level=5):
    for n in tree:
        if n.dodelete or n.visited:
            continue
        if n.level != level:
            continue
        sub_tree = tree.get_by_path(n.id)
        if sub_tree is None:
            continue
        sub_tree_stack = []
        for child in tree.get_by_path(n.id).children:
            if child.val is not None and child.val <= thresh:
                sub_tree_stack.append((child.name, child.id, child.val))
                # Also mark this for deletion
                tree.get_by_path(child.id).dodelete = True
        if sub_tree_stack:
            # Get the parent for these nodes
            node_name = n.name + ": [" + ",".join([subnode[0] for subnode in sub_tree_stack]) + "]"
            node_val = sum([subnode[2]for subnode in sub_tree_stack])
            node_id = sorted([subnode[1] for subnode in sub_tree_stack])[0]
            parent_name = n.parent.name
            parent_level = n.parent.level
            parent_id= n.parent.id
            # Now ensure that you delete the old node before adding new
            tree.get_by_path(n.id).dodelete = True

            tree.get_by_path(parent_id).add_child(Node(node_name, val=node_val, id = n.id, visited=True) )
    return tree
```

A bit complicated way of doing it, but works. I have created a gist https://gist.github.com/fahaddaniyal/0dc86c80f266fd9f8cdb for any wayward soul trying to test this out